# Where can I find all possible python -W options?

Tags: python

I want to find all possible python -W options and their meanings (e.g., python -W error is a valid option). Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Did you look through the documentation? Did you look through the source code?

Comment: I've searched through the doc but didn't find anything. I'm not familiar with the source code.

Comment: I think there should be relevant docs, this is why I'm asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The documentation is at https://docs.python.org/3/index.html

The command line options are described in the usage section.